# J field unknown in where clause Mysql

Tags: java, mysql

just as in the title I have this error every time I launch my request, do you have the solution? it seems to me that this is a problem of apostrophe

```
stm.executeUpdate("UPDATE client SET Nom='"+txtno.getText()+"',Prenom='"
+txtpr.getText()+"',DateArrivee='"+txtda.getText()
+"',DataFin='"+txtdad.getText()+"',chambre='"
+txtid.getSelectedItem().toString()+"',Nb_personne='"
+txtnomb.getText()+"',Categorie='"+txtca.getText()
+"' WHERE 'Prix'='" +txtpri.getText());
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need (') around Prix. Try without it.

Answer (score 0):

If apostrophe is the issue you can try to add slashes for apostrophe in getText method of the variables. 
Also 'Prix' stands out form other variables please check it as mentioned below

stm.executeUpdate("UPDATE client SET Nom='"+txtno.getText()+"',Prenom='"+txtpr.getText()+ "',DateArrivee='"+txtda.getText()+"',DataFin='"+txtdad.getText()+"',chambre='"+txtid.getSelectedItem().toString()+"',Nb_personne='"+txtnomb.getText()+ "',Categorie='"+txtca.getText()+"' WHERE Prix=" +txtpri.getText());